# How to use kaminari theme for zurb foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, kaminari

I want to apply a theme for zurb foundation to `kaminari` pagination.

Detault theme can be installed by `rails g kaminari:views default`.
But I couldn't figure out how to install other themes.

Especially, theme for foundation is not merged.
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes/pull/14

There is no readme in [kaminari_themes](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes), so I have no idea how to go further.
What should I do to apply the foundation theme?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Foundation was added in a recent release, so now you can do this:

```
rails g kaminari:views foundation
```

Answer (score 2):

If you generate the theme (it might not matter which one), for example

```
rails g kaminari:views bootstrap
```

You can see all of the "machinery" in the `views\kaminari\` folder. Here is my "hack" to get [Foundations Pagination](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/pagination.html) working with Kaminari:

I tweaked `_paginator.html.haml` to reflect the Foundation class on the `ul` tag:

```
= paginator.render do
  %ul.pagination
  ...
```

And I tweaked `_page.html.haml` to reflect Foundations `current` class (instead of Kaminari's `active`:

```
%li{class: "#{'current' if page.current?}"}
```

And then it just worked!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this command and it worked: `rails g kaminari:views bootstrap`. The source, [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/generators/kaminari/views_generator.rb#L96), makes it clear that he's pulling themes from his themes repo when running `rails g kaminari:views`. Pretty cool!

Answer (score 1):

A not so hacky solution would be to use theme from [RalphAtHamburg's](https://github.com/RalphAtHamburg/kaminari_themes) fork.

Simply copy [kaminari views](https://github.com/RalphAtHamburg/kaminari_themes/tree/master/foundation-5/app/views/kaminari) to `app/views/kaminari/` directory.

This is similar to what happens when you run `rails g kaminari:views [default|bootstrap|google|github]`, If these partials are present in `app/views/kaminari/` Kaminari uses them instead of the default partial views.

For more info on themes use [Kaminari Readme](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this, I have the latest version of kaminari (0.16.1) and it includes a theme for foundation. Works great out of the box!